# Empty fields remaining after splitting str w/ successive tabs from USB text on android difficult to identify

Tags: java, arrays, tabs, split, element

I'm reading a text file into an Android 4.0 tablet from a USB drive, many lines of which start with a tab. Being a quiz utility for language, a typical line is

```
[tab]an experience[crlf]
```

On splitting I have an empty array element that I can so far detect only by testing if `stringJustSplit[0].length( ) == 0`. That doesn't feel secure as length is an attribute *about* the element, but not what it equals. Of course `==""` and `== null` didn't get me anywhere.

I see the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option, but I'd rather have empty elements remain, and the program responds to them intentionally.

Is there a statement that gets a handle on them?

The Log produces:

```
    ---Array trial---(6229): Start
    ---Array trial---(6229): Located by length( )==0.
    ---Array trial---(6229): End
```

from this method:

```java
while ((Fileline = buffered_reader.readLine( )) != null) {
    line2array = Fileline.split("\\t");
    String[] tester = new String[1];
    String dummyStr = "|element1";
    String[] emptyField = dummyStr.split("\\|");
    if (true)                         {Log.v(T, "Start results");}
    if (line2array[0] == emptyField[0]){Log.v(T, "Located by array element created similar way.");}
    if (line2array[0] == tester[0])   {Log.v(T, "Located by comparison w just-made array.");}
    if (line2array[0].length( ) == 0) {Log.v(T, "Located by length( ) == 0.");}
    if (line2array[0] == "")          {Log.v(T, "Located by zero-len string.");}
    if (line2array[0] == null)        {Log.v(T, "Located by null.");}
    if (true)                         {Log.v(T, "End");}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you need the `equals` method to compare the contents of strings, `==` will compare whether the variable reference the same address in memory.

So your code would be:

```
// can't call .equals on something that is null
if (line2array[0] != null && line2array[0].equals(emptyField[0])) {
  Log.v(T, "Located by array element created similar way.");
}
if (line2array[0] != null && line2array[0].equals(tester[0])) {
  Log.v(T, "Located by comparison w just-made array.");
}
if (line2array[0].length() == 0) {
  Log.v(T, "Located by length( ) == 0.");
}
// literals are never null
if ("".equals(line2array[0])) {
  Log.v(T, "Located by zero-len string.");
}
if (line2array[0] == null) {
  Log.v(T, "Located by null.");
}
if (true) {
  Log.v(T, "End");
}
```

Comment: Superb, tehlexx, an instantly-applicable solution and a few lesson points as well. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the nice words @davon. Please remember to also accept the answer if you're happy with it.

Comment: My first post, had been searching for a shred of something called 'accept' all along @tehlexx, ... while grasping at even the doubtful guesses, finally hovered the checkmark outline ...